# Why do some emails include a link to the same destination as the button right above them?

Tags: accessibility, email, html, urls

Can someone explain the purpose behind this practice?
Is it an accessibility issue and is this practice outdated?

For example:
"If you have trouble with the link above, copy and paste this URL into your browser: [www.website.com/1234"](http://www.website.com/1234%22)

Comment: I presume back in the mists of time email software wouldn't render the graphics in emails properly.

Answer (score 1):

Some emails are classified as spam, or user open in a program out of a date, when this happen the user can't see the body of the email (made in html), and in some cases the user doesn't know how to fix, in this cases the link will help user very fast.